# update query not working in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my code:

I want to update the `total_values` field using an array. I just fetch the data's from table then i want to update the field for same table

```
// select query to get the value
    for($j=0;$j<count($capacity);$j++)
   {  
     $capaci=$capacity[$j];
    // select query to get the value
     $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT recieved-allocate*plate_quantity as ans from total_values where capacity='$capaci'"); 
     while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) 
     {
      $recieves=$fetch['ans'];
      $sql3="update total_values set recieved='$recieves' where capacity='$capaci' and month='$mon'";
      mysql_query($sql3);
     }
    }
```

Comment: There's no query being executed (and no question being asked by the way).

Comment: and please don't create sql like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1):

If i understood that this is what u are trying to do:

```
for($j=0;$j<count($capacity);$j++)
       {  
         $capaci=$capacity[$j];
        // select query to get the value
         $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT recieved-allocate*plate_quantity as ans from total_values where capacity='$capaci'"); 
         while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) 
         {
          $recieves=$fetch['ans'];
          $sql3="update total_values set recieved='$recieves' where capacity='$capaci' and month='$mon'";
          mysql_query(sql3);
         }
        }
```

And as idstam said in comments, learn to use PDO to prevent SQL injection

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. but i get wrong updation ...

Comment: ans - field name
 1   
6

Comment: what exactly is wrong with the updates?

Comment: i need the value like 1 and 6 but am getting 6 and 6

Comment: i think for loop repeat the value ... please see my updated code on top

Comment: Depends on your variables and select result, can not tell without knowing `$capacity` value and seeing contents of `total_values` table

Comment: ya correct i had declare the $capacity value before itself, am getting the value from text box. so no issue in that.. <input type="hidden" name="capacity[]" value="<?php echo $capacity; ?>">

Comment: just check your variables and table, follow it - use debugger or print_r and echo them so you can see how are they changing and what are the results of select query. Error is in another part of your code or in SQL tables

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is pretty messy, but functionally, the problem may simply be that you need to have a call to `mysql_query($sql3)` on that line after you define `$sql3`. Also, you probably want to remove the `echo` statement just before you set `$sql3`.

Comment: ya this is my query but not getting perfect answer: for($j=0;$j<count($capacity);$j++)
       {  
         $capaci=$capacity[$j];
        // select query to get the value
         $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT recieved-allocate*plate_quantity as ans from total_values where capacity='$capaci'"); 
         while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) 
         {
          $recieves=$fetch['ans'];
          $sql3="update total_values set recieved='$recieves' where capacity='$capaci' and month='$mon'";
          mysql_query($sql3);
         }
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting the mathematical result that you're expecting, maybe you have a simple error in your arithmetical operator sequence... ?

In the line of code that starts with `$sql2=mysql_query`...

You're currently saying:

```
SELECT recieved-allocate*plate_quantity as ans...
```

... but perhaps you mean to say the following?

```
SELECT (recieved-allocate)*plate_quantity as ans...
```

or [EDIT: This is a third option:]

```
SELECT recieved-(allocate*plate_quantity) as ans...
```

These statements would, of course, produce different mathematical results.

Is that the problem/solution?

Comment: no if i run this query in phpmyadmin means i can get the perfect value... i get the error in loop only.. for your reference shall i put my whole code?

Comment: It's probably best to use parenthesis to explicit specify your desired order of operations anyway. Can you try the second and (newly edited) third example here in my examples above just for kicks and let me know if it works?

Comment: ya tried it gives balance (-2 and -14) but i need (1 and 6)..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `recieved`, `allocate`, and `plate_quantity` fields are all numeric types in your MySQL table.

Comment: its varchar ...if numeric means what i have to do and

Comment: Ah!! Then that may be your problem. Are you using phpMyAdmin? If so, just use it to edit your table to make all those fields types `int(11)` instead of `varchar`. You can only perform reliable math on numeric fields.

Try it and let me know...

Comment: y i changed but also same condition. see i need two values (1 and 6) but i get (6 and 6). if i put print_r means i got this Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 1 [8] => 6 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 )    so 7th and 8th value only i need but its updating 8th value for both.

Comment: am waiting for your reply only boss